# Images not resizing properly on windows, what to do?

Tags: html, css

i have a site that has a grid of images in the center,when i see it on my 1920*1080 desktop the images are properly spaced and it works great, but when seeing it on lower resolution (or if the user resizes the window) the images move and ruin the layout of the site. I need a way to scale the images when the site is displayed in lower resolution computers or the window is smaller.

```
<div class="imagenes" style="padding: 2px 0px 20px;">
<div class="row imagenes" style="display: inline">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style= "height: 320px; width: 480px; margin-left:165px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
        <img src="images/inscrib1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style= "height: 320px; width: 480px; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: auto; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
        <img src="images/inscrib2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style= "height: 320px; width: 480px; margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 165px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
         <img src="images/inscrib3.jpg"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked into either using percentages instead of pixels, or media queries?

Comment: Why do you write inline styles? Also they won't resize cuz you hard coding the heights in pixels and not `%`, am sure you are using bootstrap so ignore writing inline styles and apply appropriate classes

Comment: As @Mr.Alien says, if you specifically set inline styles (via the `style="..."` attribute) you are automatically overriding the bootstrap settings... which appears completely pointless

Comment: @Mr.Alien could you elaborate a little? i used % in an updated version and it seems to work a little bit better, but even though i'm using bootstrap with the class "col-sm-3" 3 times the last image goes to another line, i'm stuck with this D:

Answer (score 0):

As per the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

add the "img-responsive" class to the images.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries :

```
@media screen and (max-width : **the_size_you_want**px) {

    .col-sm-3 {
        width: **idem**px;
        height: **idem**px;
    }

    .col-sm-3 img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

}
```